# Glassfish 3.1 CDI problem with multimodule layout

Tags: glassfish, cdi

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Weld or Glassfish or if I'm doing something just plain wrong.

I have three jars: api, impl and base. These jars are packaged to war that is deployed to Glassfish 3.1 (b37). The outcome is an error that states that injection point is unsatisfied in a pojo that is in impl. The failing pojo to inject is in base jar. The curious thing is that I can inject that very same failing pojo to a backing bean in my war with no fuss, and I can also just instantiate the injection dependency by hand using the old fashioned new keyword.

Any thoughts? I also have Maven based test project that replicates this if anyone is interested to see that.

Every jar has beans.xml in META-INF - even the war has beans.xml.

- Ville

Comment: I'm happy to have a look at the test project.  Add a link that I can download it from in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by replacing module weld-osgi-bundle.jar (Glassfish is shipped with weld 1.1.0.Final) in Glassfish modules directory with the newest one - 1.1.1.Final. After that remove all files from domains/domain1/osgi-cache directory.